# IE 10/11 drops blob object when printing PDF from iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, blob, internet-explorer-11

I'm trying to implement a pdf print feature based on PDFKit in my web site.
I created a PDF using PDFKit and referenced it via a blobURL with an iframe.
But if I print the iframe, it is empty. (Firefox and Chrome works fine)
IE prints the following warning:

> One or more blob urls were revoked by closing the blob for which they were created. these urls will no longer resolve as the data backing the url has been freed.

Here is my code:

```
var url = this.pdfStream.toBlobURL('application/pdf');

if (navigator.userAgent.match(/firefox/i) !== null){ //Firefox
    window.open(url, '_blank');
} else{
    $(document.body).append('<iframe id="printPreview" name="printPreview">');
    $('iframe#printPreview').url = this.pdfStream.toBlobURL('application/pdf');
    $('iframe#printPreview').attr('src', url);
    $('iframe#printPreview').load(function(){
        window.frames["printPreview"].focus();
        window.frames["printPreview"].print();
    });
}
```

Has anybody a workaround for this?
I already tried to open the BlobURL in a new window, but it also fails with IE. I also tried to store the blobURL in a window property, but it also fails.

Thanks!

Comment: IE. Blob. Printing. PDF. iFrame. So much happening here... and it's only the title! :) Re: your issue, this might be related to a security setting in IE?

Comment: If it's just in IE, maybe make a copy of the PDF (in another iframe?) and print that.